# JBoss and RedHat

Tags: jboss, redhat

JBoss is community driven so it is completely free?

and

JBoss itself works within kernel space or user space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- JBoss is a company, not a product, and is a subsidiary of RedHat.
- JBoss Application Server is open-source and is released in unsupported community edition, as well as commercially-supported Enterprise Application Platform edition.
- Like any java application, JBossAS runs in user space.